# How to make clickable cell references after pasting addresses from multidimensional array

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I have the following sub routine that I'm using to store all of the changes I make while my macro runs.

```
Public ChangeLog() As String

Sub Test()
Erase ChangeLog
'    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
'    WS.Name = "Change Log"
'    WS.Tab.Color = vbYellow
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), "Test1"
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("B2"), "Test2"
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("C2"), "Test3"
    'ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = ChangeLog
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ChangeLog, 2) + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ChangeLog)
End Sub

Function Log(Cell As Range, Reason As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Not Not ChangeLog) = 0 Then
        ReDim ChangeLog(0 To 1, 0 To 1)
        ChangeLog(0, 0) = "Cells": ChangeLog(1, 0) = "Changes Made"
        ChangeLog(0, 1) = Cell.Address: ChangeLog(1, 1) = Reason
    Else
        ReDim Preserve ChangeLog(0 To 1, 0 To UBound(ChangeLog, 2) + 1)
        ChangeLog(0, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = Cell.Address: ChangeLog(1, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = Reason
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Result:
[image: ChangeLog]

Each time I make an edit I need to note to the user I write the cell address and reason for the error to the array `ChangeLog`, which I paste into the worksheet next to the Activesheet at the end of my macro. For testing purposes I have excluded the part where I add the new spreadsheet, just so I can make sure I'm dealing with the multidimensional array correctly (it's a weakness of mine). This works well, except I would like to make the cell addresses hyperlinks/clickable, so they will bring the user to the spot on the first spreadsheet where that error is/was (depending on whether my macro cleans up or simply points on the particular error).

**So, my questions are:**

1. How can I make all of the cell references clickable when pasting them onto the new spreadsheet from the array? What would be the fastest method?
2. Is this an efficient method or is there an easier way (rather than calling the function each time)?

Comment: After pasting, loop over the cells with the addresses and add a hyperlink to each which points to the required cell.  If you record a macro while adding a link it will give you the syntax you need to use.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but is that the fastest way? Could I possibly set up the formula as I'm saving the cell address into the array, so that when it's pasted it would automatically be a link?

Comment: I don't know but it's easy to test...

Comment: i'll test it now then. As for my 2nd question, do you think this is an efficient method? I took your idea of calling a function each time to note the necessary changes.

Comment: I guess the first question would be how efficient does it need to be?  If you're logging hundreds of changes then it might not matter how you do it: if tens of thousands then probably worth spending time on.  I did a quick test and i don't think you can use HYPERLINK for this purpose: you will need to add each link after pasting to the sheet.

Comment: At first I did not think the hyperlink function would work for this, but after toying around for about an hour I've found a way to set up the hyperlink when I record the values to the array. Once I paste the entire array to the new sheet the formulas are already done and links are active/clickable. See my answer for how I did it.

Comment: Good to see you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by working with the `Hyperlink` formula and creating the formulas as I was reading the values into the array. This way when you paste the entire array to a range the formulas/links are already active and clickable, meaning you can skip the step of having to loop through each value and set up the link.

```
Public ChangeLog() As String

Sub Test()
    Erase ChangeLog
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), "Test1"
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("B2"), "Test2"
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("C2"), "Test3"
    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1))
    WS.Name = "Change Log"
    WS.Tab.Color = vbYellow
    WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ChangeLog, 2) + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ChangeLog)
End Sub

Function Log(Cell As Range, Reason As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Not Not ChangeLog) = 0 Then
        ReDim ChangeLog(0 To 1, 0 To 1)
        ChangeLog(0, 0) = "Cells": ChangeLog(1, 0) = "Changes Made"
        ChangeLog(0, 1) = "=Hyperlink(" & """#'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """,""" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """)"
        ChangeLog(1, 1) = "Hyperlink Test"
    Else
        ReDim Preserve ChangeLog(0 To 1, 0 To UBound(ChangeLog, 2) + 1)
        ChangeLog(0, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = "=Hyperlink(" & """#'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """,""" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """)"
        ChangeLog(1, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = Reason
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Results in pre-made hyperlinks:
[image: pre-made hyperlinks]

Answer (score 1):

Would the `Application.Goto` method suit your task without the need for hyperlinks at all? You could capture a `Selection_Change` event (which occurs when a cell is clicked). Given that the cell contains the address of your change cell, you could just `Goto` that address.

The sample code below gives you a skeleton idea, but more work might be needed if, for example, you didn't want to handle the `Selection_Change` event if a user *key-pressed* his way to the cell.

You mentioned that you're not so comfortable with multi-dimensional arrays. Given that we can only redim the last dimension, I have to agree they are a real fiddle when their purpose is to prepare an array that writes to the worksheet. It's just a personal preference but if I know that I'll be adding rows (ie increasing the first dimension) dynamically, then I use a different data storage method (1D array, `Collection`, `Dictionary`, etc.) and copy the data to a 2d output array just before writing it. In the code below I've used a `Collection` for example.

In a module:

```
Option Explicit
Private mChanges As Collection
Public Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim output() As String
    Dim logItems As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Log some changes
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set mChanges = New Collection
    LogChanges ws.Range("A1"), "Test1"
    LogChanges ws.Range("A2"), "Test2"
    LogChanges ws.Range("A3"), "Test3"

    'Populate the output array
    ReDim output(1 To mChanges.Count + 1, 1 To 2)
    output(1, 1) = "Cells": output(1, 2) = "Changes Made"
    i = 2
    For Each logItems In mChanges
        output(i, 1) = logItems(0)
        output(i, 2) = logItems(1)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    'Write output to sheet
    ws.Range("A1:B1").Resize(UBound(output, 1)).Value = output
    'Select cell "A1" so any cell click below "A1" can be captured
    ws.Activate: ws.Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Private Sub LogChanges(cell As Range, reason As String)
    Dim logItems(0 To 1) As String

    logItems(0) = cell.Address(False, False)
    logItems(1) = reason
    mChanges.Add logItems
End Sub
```

In your Worksheet code behind:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim desired As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Set desired = Me.Range("A2", Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If Not Intersect(Target, desired) Is Nothing Then
            'Check whether the reason is a 'go to' one -> change string as req'd
            If Target.Offset(, 1).Value2 = "Test2" Then
                Set cell = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                'Define the cell address -> amend "Sheet1" to your user sheet name.
                Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Target.Value2)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                    'Cell address is valid so go to it.
                    Application.Goto cell, True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This would suit my task, but I'd rather use hyperlinks for a few reasons. The user will visually be able to see and know that it's a hyperlink, it requires much less code since I combined the two steps into one, I've already figured out what I need to do with the multidimensional array and its working properly, and finally I already have other actions taking place under the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, so I don't want to add to it and bog down the performance anymore. Thank you though for sharing this alternative with me!